# Seeking tutorial to split group of layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, references

[image]I am trying to split a group of layers, but I can't find anything online about it. I have a layer with a paper clip on it (in the sidebar). I can't figure out how to break it.

Could you link me to a tutorial that would do this?

I don't think I am typing the correct terminology into Google. I am using QGIS

Comment: Is it an empty group? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG6hT.png. If it is an empty group you can remove it and you will no lose data. If the group contain layers, you can drag and drop them out.

Comment: Hiya, the group has already been made. When I drag out the group within the group, it works. But when I try to drag the last layers out the group (that I just dragged out) it won't let me. They go a light blue in colour and thats where I'm stuck haha. Would love to get past this, theres something silly I'm missing I'm sure of it

Comment: Please, include a screenshot in you post. Include also a description of the steps taken to create the group or groups, in a way that we can reproduce your behavior.

Comment: I was sent the data like this, I don't know how the group was made (assuming like it normally would be)

Comment: @LeviMT I updated my answer based on screenshot.

Answer (score 8):

- If you want to create a new group, click on the paper clip icon and create a sub-group, then drag it out of the original group to become a separate group and not sub-group. See the image below. Finally, select the layers you want from group 1 to the new group.

[image]

- If you want to split them and put them just as separate layers, then do not create a group and just select what you want and put them outside the group.

**Update based on screenshot**

You cannot drag the colored polygons inside the layer and drop it outside because those polygon are just symbols/styles based on the attribute table. If you right-click the layer *HGMP Habitats 2019 5 habcode copy* -> Poropeties -> Styles, you will see the symbology of that layer exactly as they are displayed styled based on the attribute table. If you want to drag some of the data as separate layer, you need to used Select by attribute and write the following expression:

"FieldName" = 'information you want to drag'

Where "FieldName" is the name of the field where the data displayed are located and 'information you want to drag' is the text under that field that you want save as separate layers. After selection, right-click the layer again -> Export -> Save selected as -> Select shapefile or any format you like and save.

Comment: Hiya, the group has already been made. When I drag out the group within the group, it works. But when I try to drag the last layers out the group (that I just dragged out)  it won't let me. They go a light blue in colour and thats where I'm stuck haha

Comment: @LeviMT Could you please edit your question and add a screenshot of the problem. It will be much better. There is an [edit] button under your question.

Comment: I just did a step by step breakdown of what I am doing. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ah okay. Do I list all the names after "FieldName" = 'information you want to drag'. I.e. "FieldName" = 'information you want to drag' 'FieldName" = 'information you want to drag'. Or do I have to do one for each?

Comment: Appreciate your help with this!

Comment: If you want to select more that one parameter then you can use `"FieldName" in ('information you want to drag 1', 'information you want to drag 2', and so on)`